# "Cannot do shipment for order" API Fatal error

Tags: magento-1.8, api

My Magento application is connected to 3rd party system that manages orders and also updates shipping tracking information using Magento's Soap API.

But for few orders we are facing

```
#<SOAP::FaultError: Cannot do shipment for order.
```

and due to this shipping tracking information is not updated.

I am not able to figure out What could be possible reason for such error?

Has any one faced such issue? whats need's to be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That error message is coming from the shipment API and is:

```
     /**
     * Check shipment create availability
     */
    if (!$order->canShip()) {
         $this->_fault('data_invalid', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cannot do shipment for order.'));
    }
```

canShip checks to see if any part of the order contains a virtual product. I would check that all your products are physical products that are eligible for shipping. E.g. not product type virtual.

Comment: Thanks James, but I don't have any virtual product on my store. All are Simple product.